# Wrong cost adjacency matrix

Tags: c++, graph-theory

I try to obtain the adjacency matrix of weights, and then use it in the calculation of the minimum weight path. There is a problem, when I try to display it, I get a wrong result :
By logic, the diagonal must have only 0, and in the places where the vertices are adjacent, must be the weight of the edge
[image]

```
//set the source and destination of each edge
g->edge[0]->src = 0;
g->edge[0]->dest = 1;
g->edge[0]->weight = 9;

g->edge[1]->src = 0;
g->edge[1]->dest = 10;
g->edge[1]->weight = 6;

g->edge[2]->src = 1;
g->edge[2]->dest = 2;
g->edge[2]->weight = 3;

g->edge[3]->src = 1;
g->edge[3]->dest = 10;
g->edge[3]->weight = 2;

g->edge[4]->src = 2;
g->edge[4]->dest = 3;
g->edge[4]->weight = 2;

g->edge[5]->src = 2;
g->edge[5]->dest = 6;
g->edge[5]->weight = 3;

g->edge[6]->src = 2;
g->edge[6]->dest = 5;
g->edge[6]->weight = 3;

g->edge[7]->src = 3;
g->edge[7]->dest = 4;
g->edge[7]->weight = 5;

g->edge[8]->src = 4;
g->edge[8]->dest = 5;
g->edge[8]->weight = 4;

g->edge[9]->src = 6;
g->edge[9]->dest = 10;
g->edge[9]->weight = 2;

g->edge[10]->src = 6;
g->edge[10]->dest = 7;
g->edge[10]->weight = 9;

g->edge[11]->src = 7;
g->edge[11]->dest = 8;
g->edge[11]->weight = 7;

g->edge[12]->src = 7;
g->edge[12]->dest = 9;
g->edge[12]->weight = 2;

g->edge[13]->src = 8;
g->edge[13]->dest = 9;
g->edge[13]->weight = 7;

g->edge[14]->src = 9;
g->edge[14]->dest = 10;
g->edge[14]->weight = 5;
```

My code :

```
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
        adjacency_matrix[i][i] = 0;
        for (j = i + 1; j < numberOfVertices; j++)
        {
                adjacency_matrix[i][j] = g->edge[i]->weight;
                adjacency_matrix[j][i] = g->edge[i]->weight;
        }
    }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Post a [mcve] including your debugging observations as required here please.

Comment: you are not using `src` and `dest` at all as you build your matrix...

Comment: @Peter yeah, I realized what I did wrong. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
        adjacency_matrix[i][i] = 0;
        for (j = i + 1; j < numberOfVertices; j++)
        {
                adjacency_matrix[i][j] = g->edge[i]->weight;
                adjacency_matrix[j][i] = g->edge[i]->weight;
        }
    }
```

In this code you are setting **every** edge from vertex i to every other vertex to the **same** weight.  I do not think this is what you want.

( Note: It is hard to know what you do want.  When reporting a problem you need to include a description of both what happens AND what you wanted to happen.  "It's wrong!" is almost useless as a bug report. )

Comment: I realized what I did wrong. I had to use   
adjacency_matrix[g->edge[i]->src][g->edge[i]->dest]= g->edge[i]->weight;
adjacency_matrix[g->edge[i]->src][g->edge[i]->dest] = g->edge[i]->weight;